# Correct syntax for the WHERE by date

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

This is the part that I dont know the syntax
I want that my form automatically loads the data from the Database
by using the b_date but only display the records if there is a match in month and date
not using the year, The program is like a Birthday Reminder

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Bene_dbDataSet.bene_records' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Bene_recordsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Bene_dbDataSet.bene_records)

        con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\RedemptorisMater\Desktop\S\K\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bene_db.mdb"

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim Sql As String


        Sql = "SELECT * FROM bene_records"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, con)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)

        con.Close()

        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\R\Desktop\S\Kenton\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bday1.wav",
        AudioPlayMode.Background)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention where you will specify the day and month, so to get a specific D/M:

```
SELECT bene_records.*, Day([b_date]) AS MyDay, Month([b_date]) AS MyMonth
FROM bene_records
WHERE (((Day([b_date]))=1) AND ((Month([b_date]))=11));
```

You can replace the hard-coded date/month with your own criteria.